# Header Customization

Tags: magento2, header, edit

I need to make a header like attached any help will be appreciated

can some one guide me how to achiev that step by step because I am new in magento

Using Mangento 2.1.7
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To have a custom header you will need to edit the header.phtml file on your server.

The directory is:

```
app/design/frontend/*Theme Name*/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
```

You can add your code there.

Comment: Save a backup of the original header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want customised header then you can create custom  phtml with custom header links and menu and call into the `default.xml` file.

```
app/design/frontend/*Theme Name*/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

You can call this custom phtml file like this way in your container.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YoutTemplateFile.location].phtml"}}
```